# github nothing to commit working directory clean

Tags: git, github

After modifying some part of the code and adding some files, I typed `git add .`, before committing, I did some thing stupid with `git stash`, then I tried to commit, but I got the message

```
 #On branch master
 nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This is the first time I use github, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: @ Sirko, I tried `stash-unapply`, still doesn't work.

Comment: I guess you need to use `git stash apply` to "recover" your changes from the stash.

Comment: @Sirko Cool, this works, thank you. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recover changes, you stashed before, you can use

```
git stash apply
```

For more details:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing